# How to get details of running applications on Terminal?

Tags: terminal, python, activity-monitor

I have found that using activity monitor I get all the information I need. I now just need a way to access this information via preferably Python or even Bash and Apple Script. I just need to get the information at regular intervals and put it in a log file while my program is running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The terminal command `top` will give you a list of running processes biggest ones first. Do `man top` and you will have a complete explanation of the syntax for your version.

Also of interest might be `ps`, especially if used in scripts. Run `man ps` for the details.

So, just to add this will give the initial information without any processes shown:

```
top -o cpu -O +rsize -s 5 -n 0
```

Based on the example shown in the man page for top.
And this is what it looks like :
[image]

Comment: Thanks @patrix I should have respected the formatting... And I will be looking at the ps command.

Comment: thank you! I had another doubt. Is there any way to get only the total cpu usage and memory usage not related to any specific process. Basically, the first dew lines when top is given. I tried to grep, but I can't grep those lines.

Comment: top -o <key> , the definition of key is given in the man page, for the cpu use it is <cpu>.

Comment: top -o sorts the list based on the key. What I want are the total CPU and memory usage. Not for a single application

Comment: The man page gives the example top -o cpu -O +rsize -s 5 -n 20, which if you change -n 20 to -n 0 will not show any processes but just the initial information : processes load average ...

Comment: Thanks a lot, mate. This was what I was looking for. Must have skipped over it in the man page.

Comment: good luck with grep getting the bits you want !